# UK - Do I pay higher Stamp Duty for transfer of equity on main home if I have Buy To Let property?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, property

It is my understanding that if you own a BTL (Buy To Let) property and a residential property, and then move house, you pay the standard stamp duty (without the 3% surcharge for second homes) even if it is a bigger house.

I am hoping the rules are similar for transfer of equity. For example, I have a BTL property which I own myself. I also have a residential home which I live in and which I own 50-50 with my brother (we are tenants in common). I would like to buy his share, but will I have to pay the 3% surcharge?

Comment: If you don’t get a suitable reply here, you could try over at [MoneySE](https://money.stackexchange.com/) where they have [stamp-duty](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stamp-duty) and [home-equity](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/home-equity) tags.  But you should check if it would be [on-topic](https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) first to be on the safe side.

Comment: Can you just clarify that you're buying out the 50% from your main residence not the BTL, please. And  if you're joint tenants or tenants in common?

Comment: @Rick good point, I have made the post more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [link](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/stamp-duty-land-tax-buying-an-additional-residential-property#hr-notapply) there are some scenarios where higher rate Stamp Duty does not apply:

> If you want to increase the amount of a property that you already own,
> you do not have to pay the higher rates when all the following apply:
>
> - you already own 25% or more
> - the dwelling has been your only or main home for the previous 3 years
> - if you’re extending a lease, your lease
>   still has 21 years or more left to run

since the first two points are true, and the third one is conditional, I believe that I do not have to pay higher rates.